# Download files asynchronously through FTP in java

Tags: java, multithreading, ftp, ftp-client

I need to download multiple files through FTP in java. For this I wrote a code using FTPClient which is taking files one by one to download.
I need to take files from a server and download to another network. After I wrote the code, I found that downloading is taking more time to download each file as the file sizes are huge (more than 10GB). I decided to multithread the process i.e. run multiple files at a time. Can anybody help writing me FTP in multithreaded environment.
Although I feel that multithreading won't help as bandwidth of the network would remain same and would be divided among multiple threads and leading to slow download again. Please suggest!!

Answer (score 1):

You have different stuff to check first:

- your download speed
- remote server's upload speed
- maximum server upload speed for each connection

If the server limits the transfer speed for a single file to a threshold lower than it's maximum transfer speed, you can have some advantages by using multi-threading (e.g. with a limit of 10 Kb/s per connection and a maximum upload of 100 Kb/s, you can theoretically have 10 downloads in parallel). If not, multi-threading will not help you.

Also if your download is saturated (all your bandwidth is filled with a single download or the server's upload bandwidth is greater than your download) you will not have any kind of help by multi-threading.

If your multi-threading will be useful, just instantiate a new connection for each file and throw it in a separated thread.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Talking about the download speed -- I could see my file getting downloaded to a network at 10kb/s for a single file which took around 45min to download an 8GB file. So when I have like 5 files of more than 10GB size and I run them in parallel, I wonder how would it respond. While manual download was taking little lesser time and we wanted to automate this through java!! Although, not sure how a server can limit a file to a threshold when we have multiple files running.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel that multithreading won't help as bandwidth of the network would remain same and would be divided among multiple threads and leading to slow download again.

That could well be true.   Indeed, if you have too many threads trying to download files at the same time, you are likely to either overload the FTP server or cause network congestion.  Both can result in a net **decrease** in the overall data rate.

The solution is to use a bounded thread pool for the download threads, and tune the pool size.

It is also a good idea to reuse connections where possible, since creating a connection and authenticating the user take time ... and CPU resources at both ends.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Stephen C!! bounded thread pool is new for me.. Could you give any reference for the same? Also, not sure about tuning the pool size.

Comment: 1) Well the simple way is to use an ExecutorService; see the Executors javadoc.  2) Adjust, measure, repeat.